# How to call multiple functions in document.ready

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to write multiple document ready calls in one line or do you have to do them separately?

```
var pageCall = {
    first:
       function(){
           //code here
       },
    second:
       function(){
           // code here
       }
}

$(document).ready(pageCall.first, pageCall.second);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    pageCall.first();
    pageCall.second();
});
```

Or a function property of pageCall that calls both:

```
var pageCall = {
    first:
      function(){
        //code here
      },
    second:
      function(){
         // code here
      }
    foobar: 
       function () { pageCall.first(); pageCall.second(); }
 }

$(document).ready(pageCall.foobar);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all `$(document).ready()` is deprecated (still work but deprecated) it will be better to use `$(function(){ })` instead, like :

```
$(function(){
     pageCall.first();
     pageCall.second();
});
```

Comment: so just make it an annonymous function then?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @Keith :(

Comment: Yes, that would be an anonymous function inside the `ready()` handler.

Comment: nevermind, i was thinking of (function($){  // code })($);, i guess it can be written differently

Comment: Yes, as you need.. take a look to the severals format in https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: i'm just trying to be able to load and use page as fast as possible